# App Engine Load Testing

Tags: google-app-engine, jmeter, load-testing

I want to load test my web app on app engine, simulating multiple users logging in and hammering the app with requests.

I am new to Jmeter and don't know it too well but based on some research, I should be able to simulate logins with multiple accounts, credentials residing in a CSV files. I used the recording controller feature in Jmeter to simulate a test of one user logging in my app engine webapp. my app using Google Authorization.  Now my problem is once I've created the CSV file config in Jmeter and the variables, USERNAME and PASSWD and the csv files, where do I plugin those fields? Looking at the requests generated by the recording proxy, I can't seem to find the point at which an actual post to a login form is made. The closest thing to a login attempt request that I see is a HTTP Request called '/_ah/conflogin', though it is a get request and not a post and the only variable present there is something called 'state'.

Am I approaching this all wrong. Will Jmeter allow me to load test an authorized app in app engine? I found very scare resources on this online..Though I have found Google IO talks mentioning Jmeter as a stress testing tool for a web app in engine but with no details as to how to. I am not stuck on Jmeter either, just curious as to what is the 'right' way to go about load testing an app engine web application that requires login. I guess I can also do this programmatically instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely you are approaching this problem the right way.  My first recommendation would be to make sure you are recording a fresh session, so you can be sure the username and password are both sent and recorded. As an example, open an incognito window in Chrome - this will not have any previous session state, so you can be sure the entire authorization chain is executed.

BTW, you should likely ignore anyone who says you don't need to load test an app running on AppEngine because AppEngine scales. Yes, AppEngine scales very well, as does the datastore. But your application may not - there are plenty of ways to introduce scalability problems into an application.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go. I am already taking measures of modifying code in my app so that it scales, from the app engine monitoring tool appstats. But getting jmeter working would definitely be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the two concepts you are trying to address/test are different.

If you want to test page functionality, whether driven by CSV or previous recordings, try something like [selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/).

If you want to test how your application behaves under strain use JMeter. Have a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=lFarE1hH0ss) from Google I/O 2013 where Matt Stephenson shows how he used it.

Answer (score -2):

What are you trying to stress test? Google AppEngine? Don't - it scales. Trust Google and other developers that have 1000s of requests per second.

If you have a bottleneck in the app (entity groups, transactions, concurrently updating same entity), then just test that part of code via [unit tests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests). You can test concurrent operations  (and triggering retry in your code).

Comment: the backend scales but the app may not and the issue may not be detected through unit tests as they may only appear with load.

Comment: Apps on AppEngine must use AppEngine API which is by it's nature distributed, so it scales. The only contention is if you try to write to the same entity.

Comment: yes but the issue may come from custom bas code. It always happen no?

Comment: Actually you should test AppEngine apps. Yes they scale, but at a cost.